# Live Alpine Linux can't find any disks

Tags: alpine-linux, livecd

I've been making a bootable, CLI Alpine Linux recovery disk, but Cfdisk can't find any disks to partition, neither does setup-disk, what are the steps I need to take to have a functioning partition manager on a live Alpine Linux?

Comment: Are the drives managed by Intel RST or some motherboard's RAID, perhaps?

Comment: No none are RAID or RST. Just a normal SSD that my host Linux users a installed on. @ChanganAuto